# Decrease width size with margin-left,right : auto

Tags: html, css

I set the container of the elements at the center by using below method

```
margin-left : auto; margin-right: auto;
```

BUT.. when my elements need to be decrease its size by

```
-webkit-transition-property: width ;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
```

this CSS method

My elements decrease from both side which I want it to be decrease from right to left.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this ?

Please advice, Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner container (which is floated to left) and resize it with the -webkit-transition. So, the outer container stays on center and inner container decreases to the left.

```
<div id="ex1">
    <div id="ex2" />
</div>
```

Here is an example of it: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2cvw/)